# Swig wrapping typedef struct

Tags: swig

Trying to wrap a binary library where the headerfile defines a `typedef struct x x_t` where struct x has not been defined. How can i define a interface file that allows python to use the type defed structure in the Functions defined below.

## myconnection.h

```
typedef int myConnectionError;

// Note: this struct does not exist
// The typedef is done to strengthen type checking
typedef struct _myConnectionHandle* myConnectionHandle;

myConnectionError myConnectionOpen( const char *x , const char *y , myConnectionHandle *hand);
```

## myconnection.i

```
% module myconnection
%{
#include "myconnection.h"
%}

%include "myconnection.h"
```

## Example of Working C/C++ code

```
myConnectionHandle chandle;
myConnectionError error;
error = myConnectionOpen("foo","bar",&chandle);
```

## Expected Python code

```
import myconnection
handle = myconnection.myConnectionHandle
err = myconnection.myConnectionOpen("foo","1080",handle)
```

## Python result

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import myconnection
>>> handle = myconnection.myConnectionHandle()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myConnectionnHandle'
```

Comment: The comment for `typedef struct _myConnectionHandle* myConnectionHandle;` is odd; says struct does not exist, yet the typedef must point to an actual class/struct. What is declaration for `_myConnectionHandle`? Note (probably not related) the handle type is for pointer to struct, but the arg is pointer to handle, is this really your intention.

Comment: the struct _myConnectionHandle is not defined in the .h file. this is the source of the problem. The compiled library certainly have a definition of this struct internally. But using the library one only needs to deal with pointers to the library.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python doesn't support output parameters, the typical way is to create a set of typemaps that suppress having to pass an output parameter and instead use a temporary value internally that is appended to the return value.  Here's a minimal example that converts the handles to and from Python integer objects:

```
%typemap(in) myConnectionHandle %{
    $1 = (myConnectionHandle)PyLong_AsVoidPtr($input);
%}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) myConnectionHandle* (void* tmp) %{
    $1 = (myConnectionHandle*)&tmp;
%}
%typemap(argout) myConnectionHandle* %{
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,PyLong_FromVoidPtr(*$1));
%}
```

The first typemap converts a Python integer to a `myConnectionHandle` to be used as an input to a function.

The second typemap tells SWIG to ignore `myConnectionHandle*` on input since it is an output parameter, and just use a temporary value to store the handle in when calling the function.

The third typemap tells SWIG to append the returned handle value to the return result, converting it to a list of `[retval, handle]` if necessary.

Here's an example using your `myconnection.h` but I added a function to take a handle as input as well and added some dummy implementation of the functions to get it to compile.

```
%module myconnection
%{
    #include "myconnection.h"
    myConnectionError myConnectionOpen( const char *x , const char *y , myConnectionHandle *hand)
    {
        static int something;
        *hand = (myConnectionHandle)&something;
        return 0;
    }
    void useConnection(myConnectionHandle h)
    {
    }
%}

%typemap(in) myConnectionHandle %{
    $1 = (myConnectionHandle)PyLong_AsVoidPtr($input);
%}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) myConnectionHandle* (void* tmp) %{
    $1 = (myConnectionHandle*)&tmp;
%}

%typemap(argout) myConnectionHandle* %{
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,PyLong_FromVoidPtr(*$1));
%}

%include "myconnection.h"
```

Output:

```
>>> import myconnection
>>> retval, handle = myconnection.myConnectionOpen('foo','bar')
>>> myconnection.useConnection(handle)
>>>
```